# Getting Error while downloading file (from local system) in android

Tags: android

**Download.java**

```
package com.example.download_file;

import java.io.File;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStream;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import java.net.URL;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.os.Environment;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class Download extends Activity {

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_download);

       final Button downloadbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.download_button);

       final  EditText text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.download_filename);

       downloadbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()

 {


            @Override

            public void onClick(View v)
 {

       download();

       text.setText("success");

    }

       });

    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_download, menu);

        download();

        return true;

    }

   public void download()

    {

        final  EditText text=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.download_filename);

        final  EditText localname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.localname);

    try {

        String name=text.getText().toString();

        String sdcardname=localname.getText().toString();

        URL url = new URL(name);

        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();


        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);


        urlConnection.connect();


        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();


        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,sdcardname);


        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();


        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

        int downloadedSize = 0;

     .
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bufferLength = 0;  

        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {

            fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);




        }


        fileOutput.close();


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    }

}
```

1)

**input: url**= "\192.168.0.103\shared\file.txt"

**error**:  java.net.MalformedURLException:Protocol not found :\192.168.0.103\shared\file.txt

2)

**input :url**= "file://192.168.0.103/shared/file.txt"

**error** : java.lang.ClassCastEXception : org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection

Comment: Which error?Log please

Comment: `"\192.168.0.103\shared\file.txt"` is not a valid url. You need to have a protocol, like `http://` infront of it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` Take a look here: link [AsyncTask](http://steveliles.github.com/android_s_asynctask.html) may be this can help you solve your problem.

Comment: 02-19 19:59:54.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-19 19:59:54.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3405): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection
02-19 19:59:54.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):  at com.example.download_file.Download.download(Download.java:58)
02-19 19:59:54.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):  at com.example.download_file.Download$1.onClick(Download.java:34)
02-19 19:59:54.039: E/AndroidRuntime(3405):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)

Comment: @FoamyGuy i am able to download the file but it is having size 0 ..  dont know why ...  Also when i try downloading file from internet say "www.google.com"  i am getting the correct file ...

Comment: Please help i am getting the file size 0 when i download the file !!

Comment: No i haven't used the asynctask. Is it necessary to use the asynchtask to download file ....   Thanks ...

Comment: yes i tried using asynch task STILL i am getting filesize 0 !!     Download_File d=new Download_File(); d.doInBackground("http://172.16.40.56:8080/shared/remotetest.txt");